# Twilio SendGrid emails stuck in processing

Tags: java, twilio, sendgrid

I'm trying to integrate Twilio email verification in my application. Here's the code:

```java
 public EmailVerificationDto sendVerificationEmail(String recipient) {
        Verification verification = Verification.creator(
                        PATH_SERVICE_SID,
                        recipient,
                        "email")
                .setChannelConfiguration(
                        new HashMap<>() {{
                            put("template_id", TEMPLATE_ID);
                            put("from", SENDER_EMAIL);
                            put("from_name", "Puggle");
                        }})
                .create();

        return new EmailVerificationDto(
                verification.getTo(),
                verification.getSid(),
                verification.getStatus(),
                verification.getDateCreated().toLocalDate()
        );
    }
```

I can see the email on the dashboard but it's stuck on processing:

[image: stuck]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same problem, seems like SendGrid have problem with people using the service for fraudulent use so you need to get verified first. On the top of the page, you probably have a message saying that you need to get verified. You will need to fill a form, then they will contact you via email to gather some more information and accept or deny your access to the service.

Comment: Twilio SendGrid Support url - https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 1):

My cause was different to the original poster's but an email will appear to be stuck in processing if you use SendGrid's delay feature (the API lets you set a time for the email to be sent, and it sits in Processing until the send time is reached).